# Is there a way to communicate (in Wi-Fi) with a device which isn't connected to any AP but which have its Wi-Fi activated ?

Tags: python, wifi, scapy

Everything is in the title but I'll try to explain why I want to do that ;)

In fact I'm currently developing a system (mainly based on python) which try to furnish statistics concerning the presence or not of people in a dedicated place. Those statistics are based on smartphone Wifi packet emission.

For the moment I'm able to listen every "probe request" emitted. The problem is that probe request are not emitted continuously and so we lose precision concerning the presence or not of a smartphone at a given moment.

So to summarize, I'd like to do a "**kind** of ping" on smartphones which aren't connected to a network to know in a almost continuously way if someone is in the monitored place.

Hope I've been clear ! If not don't hesitate to ask for details :)
Thank you in advance !

P.S : Please apologize me if my English is not so good :')